# What is the correct way to load modules/classes from lib/ when using the config.threadsafe! option?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've been working on getting our Rails 2.3.8 app running correctly under JRuby. Everything works great until I enable **config.threadsafe!** in order to achieve the concurrency that JRuby offers. This caused modules and classes in **lib/** to no longer autoload.

with config.threadsafe! enabled:

```
$ ruby script/runner -e production 'p Sim::Sim200Provisioner'

/Users/amchale/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.5.1@web-services/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:105:in `const_missing': uninitialized constant Sim::Sim200Provisioner (NameError)
    from (eval):1
```

with config.threadsafe! disabled:

```
$ ruby script/runner -e production 'p Sim::Sim200Provisioner'
Sim::Sim200Provisioner
```

The file in question is **lib/sim/sim200_provisioner.rb** where **Sim** is **app/models/sim.rb**. Rails normally has no trouble finding and loading the file.

Do I need to manually require all of our libs, or is there a more Rails-like way to handle it that I'm missing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Rails/Configuration.html#M002069) of `threadsafe!` mentions that it disables automatic dependency loading. The reason is that there might be race conditions during the loading of files if two or more threads both decide they are still missing a certain class.

Instead, you should manually `require` all files you need in an `initializer`.

Answer (score 2):

Change `config.autoload_paths` to `config.eager_load_paths`

(based on [Rails issue #6850](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/6850#issuecomment-6567273) and [Force reload! from lib directory in rails 3.2 console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12541655/force-reload-from-lib-directory-in-rails-3-2-console#answers), [Adding lib to 'config.autoload_paths' in Rails 3 does not autoload my module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4074830/adding-lib-to-config-autoload-paths-in-rails-3-does-not-autoload-my-module/17662390#answer-17662390))

Answer (score 0):

The documentation link contains no info, thus here's some relevant doc for #threadsafe! :

> Enable threaded mode. Allows
>   concurrent requests to controller
>   actions and multiple database
>   connections. Also disables automatic
>   dependency loading after boot, and
>   disables reloading code on every
>   request, as these are fundamentally
>   incompatible with thread safety.