# Adding lib to 'config.autoload_paths' in Rails 3 does not autoload my module

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I place a file name g.rb in side `Rails.root/lib` folder
The file content is like this:

```
module Google
end
```

Then I add

```
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib #{Rails.root}/app/delayed_jobs)
```

to my `Rails.root/config/application.rb`

However, when I try to invoke Google from `rails console`, an exception is thrown. The exception goes away only if I execute `require 'google'`. 
Why? Shouldn't my file is autoloaded and shouldn't I access the module without any extra `require` statement?

Answer (score 113):

Hmm, I discovered an interesting thing. In order for Rails to auto load my class, the class name should be compliant to the file name and the folder structure.
For example, if I want to have Google module autoloaded, I must placed it inside `google.rb`, directly under /lib (incase I specify autoload from /lib).
If I want to auto load `Google::Docs`, then I either place it inside `google.rb` or `google/docs.rb`

Comment: so is this a bug or a convention?

Comment: I believe this is convention. Rails takes constant names and makes paths out of them. :: gets turned into / for this purpose. So Google::Docs turns into google/docs.rb. You could debate the usefulness of this, but that's my understanding of the current functionality.

Comment: It's not a convention per se, it's the way the Ruby interpreter looks for things, as far as I know

Comment: Wow, this just happened to me.  I don't really care about the convention, I can rename my modules.  I just would have never guessed this.  +1.

Comment: I had the same problem so I added <Module>:: before my class according to the directory and now it complains when <Module>::A references B from the same module, any ideas?

Comment: It's a Rails convention, not a Ruby one

Comment: Man I found myself for hours trying to get autoloaded paths working

Comment: Quickly want to chime in with my experience.
First of all for a lot of issues, check out the way Discourse does it. https://github.com/discourse. Personally, I had lib/rhyme_engine.rb then a lib/rhyme_engine folder, and that folder contained file like, engine.rb which looked like class RhymeEngine::Engine

Answer (score 27):

I had a similar problem with getting my module to run on Heroku. In addition to the autoload naming convention stated by Stephen C, I found out that the module code must be `require`'d due to a `threadsafe` assumption made by the Rails' production environment on Heroku (even though `threadsafe` was commented out in my `production.rb` configuration file.) As soon as I `require`'d the module file before calling `include` on the module, everything started to work.

```
require 'mymodule'
include Mymodule
```

Please take a look at [this excellent article](http://www.williambharding.com/blog/technology/rails-3-autoload-modules-and-classes-in-production) on the subject of getting Modules to load correctly in Heroku (production).

Comment: +1 This should be the accepted answer. The link should help anyone and thread safety was actually my problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 24):

That's because the point of autoload is *not* to 'require' everything up front (startup penalty). Classes are loaded as they are needed/referenced. In order to do this, you need some way to know where to look for the class. Otherwise, you would have to load every file in the autoload directory in advance to see what classes are declared. It's a tradeoff, but requiring everything in advance (as marbaq suggests) is not autoloading.
You can use the autoload command as provided by Ruby, which takes two arguments, the module to load (symbolized, i.e. :Google in your case), and the second argument is the filename, which would be g.rb if lib is in your load path ($:). See the Ruby docs for autoload.

Comment: Btw, convention says you should just rename lib/g.rb to lib/google.rb and be on your way.

Answer (score 7):

Change `config.autoload_paths` to `config.eager_load_paths`

(based on [Rails issue #6850](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/6850#issuecomment-6567273) and [Force reload! from lib directory in rails 3.2 console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12541655/force-reload-from-lib-directory-in-rails-3-2-console#answers))

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem just now, and my "solution" (or rather workaround) was to manually require every needed file from Rails.root/lib in my application.rb.

```
require 'lib/message'
require 'lib/store'
require 'lib/vault/vault.rb'
require 'lib/custom_loggers'

module MyApplication
  class Application < Rails::Application
```

My next step would be to categorize the files in module folders as you mention.

Comment: Hi @morbaq, today I had the same issue and your solution works perfectly, just wanted to say thank you :D

Answer (score -5):

i found this solution recently

**config/application.rb**

```
module AppName
  class Application < Rails::Application

    # Custom directories with classes and modules you want to be autoloadable.
    config.autoload_paths += Dir[Rails.root.join('app', 'models', '{**}')]
    config.autoload_paths += Dir[Rails.root.join('app', 'lib', 'extensions')] 

  end
end
```

the first config call induces rails to auto-load all sub-directories of the app/models directory
so now i can have /app/models/sub_directory/model.rb auto-loaded
(handy for organising an app with a large code base)

the second config call induces rails to autoload the lib/extensions directory

hope this helps

*note: i believe this is rails 3 specific*