# How can I use a model from a gem in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have a gem that has some ActiveRecord-derived models.  They are tested and work.

I've added a dependency to that gem, but when I try to access pages that refer to that model in a form_for statement, for example, I get the dreaded method_missing error:

`undefined method`mygem_mymodel_path'`

Note I had the models in my app/models directory as is usual and all was well; migrating my models to this gem has been the cause for grief.

**UPDATE 1:
In response to Robin's question:**

```
> rails console
> MyModel
=> MyGem::MyModel(id:string, name:string)
```

**Update 2: For Robin's request for form code**
Form erb:

```
<%= form_for(MyModel.new, :remote => true, :html => { :class => "new_mymodel_form", :id => "new_mymodel_form"}) do |f| -%>
```

After Robin's suggestions, this is the only way I've found around it:

**UPDATE 3: a ugly workaround**

With a model called Mymodel and a module called MyModule:

```
post '/mymodels', to: 'mymodels#create', as: 'my_module_mymodels
```

Because 'as' let's you control the path symbol name.  I'd much rather use 'resources' macro, but it seems it doesn't know to add the module name to the path symbol when it creates it, even though form_for appends the module name. I assume there is a way to solve this, but I can't find anything about this scenario.

Comment: I think I've been bitten by this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4074830/adding-lib-to-config-autoload-paths-in-rails-3-does-not-autoload-my-module.  Am about to find out.

Comment: Your error does not mean that the model can't be found. It's about the routes. To make sure your app is loading your model, run the console `rails s` and type the name of your model.

Comment: That's a good pointer, thank you.  I'm looking in that direction now.  I verified that the model is known by Rails using the console, thanks.

Comment: I'm using resource :model  in my routes.  I can only guess that this 'macro' is unable to do the right thing. I've tried include MyModule in that file (as well as elsewhere 'earlier' in the application load process), but I'm wondering if the problem isn't that I'm using a symbol from a different module.

I suppose I can just write the 7 paths 'resource' creates...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `scope`:

```
scope :as => "mymodule" do
  resources :my_resources
end
```