# How do I add a Ruby library to my app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've trying to use the [sharefile-ruby](https://github.com/avguchenko/sharefile-ruby) library, which is a wrapper for the ShareFile API.

There is no gem for it, so I believe I have to add the .rb file manually. Every library I've used I just install the gem, so I'm not sure what to do here.

Also, to use this library, would I just add `require 'sharefile-ruby'` in each controller I'm trying to use it in?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4074830/adding-lib-to-config-autoload-paths-in-rails-3-does-not-autoload-my-module

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The library is a [single Ruby file](https://github.com/avguchenko/sharefile-ruby/blob/master/sharefile-ruby.rb). Just place the file somewhere in your app and require it with:

```
require 'sharefile-ruby'
```

Of course, if you place it in lib/foo/sharefile-ruby.rb then you'll need to use:

```
require 'foo/sharefile-ruby'
```

and so on.

Comment: Is there any specific folder that these type of files are usually placed in? Rails is so oriented around convention, I just figured I can't go ahead and place this wherever I please.

Comment: i'd recommend `require './sharefile-ruby'`. usually you would like to put such files in vendor/ folder - `require './vendor/sharefile-ruby'`

Comment: Awesome, thanks. And then I just require it in each controller I'm going to be using it in? Or is there way I can only require it once and then use it anywhere?