# Force reload! from lib directory in rails 3.2 console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, irb

I have a simple class in a file in `lib/simple.rb`.

In the console (`rails c`) I have a couple of problems:

1. Rails seems unable to load the file even though `application.rb` contains `config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib/**)`. How to make Rails 3.2 behave like Rails 2.x used to (I never had problems in Rails 2.x with this autoload stuff - Rails 3 seems like a step back :( )
2. If I make a change to `simple.rb` and call `reload!` in console, it does not reload the file. I have to do `load "#{Rails.root}/lib/simple.rb` to make it reload. Is there a way to make `reload!` work like it used to in Rails 2.x? i.e. just make it reload all files without having to use `load` at all?

Answer (score 2):

It should be the folder containing the class you want to load. Therefore, should be

```
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)
```

If your app is `threadsafe!`, change `config.autoload_paths` to `config.eager_load_paths`. Once you do this, `reload!` **should** behave as you've described.